# EC2 amazon instance socket programming

Tags: c++, sockets, amazon-ec2

i am trying to do socket programming using client/server c++ code that I found on Microsoft website, my pc is suppose to be the client, and my EC2 amazon instance is suppose to be the server, I have been trying for too long to connect them, still I get "unable to connect to server".

I know that the server IP address should be passed as an argument, but still I don't know what am I suppose to but in the function getaddrinfo() at the server side.

the code I am using for the client:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
  #pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
  #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
  #pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


 #define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
 #define DEFAULT_PORT "3000"

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{

WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
    *ptr = NULL,
    hints;
const char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int iResult;
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

// Validate the parameters
if (argc != 2) {
    printf("usage: %s server-name\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
}

// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

// Resolve the server address and port
iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
        ptr->ai_protocol);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        continue;
    }
    break;
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Send an initial buffer
iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

// shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Receive until the peer closes the connection
do {

    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if (iResult > 0)
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
    else if (iResult == 0)
        printf("Connection closed\n");
    else
        printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

} while (iResult > 0);

// cleanup
closesocket(ConnectSocket);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
}
```

the code I am using for the server:

```
#include "stdafx.h"


#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

int __cdecl main(void)
{
WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult;

SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;

int iSendResult;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

// Resolve the server address and port
iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result-
>ai_protocol);
if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Setup the TCP listening socket
iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Accept a client socket
ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// No longer need server socket
closesocket(ListenSocket);

// Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
do {

    iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if (iResult > 0) {
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);

        // Echo the buffer back to the sender
        iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);
        if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
    }
    else if (iResult == 0)
        printf("Connection closing...\n");
    else {
        printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

} while (iResult > 0);

// shutdown the connection since we're done
iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// cleanup
closesocket(ClientSocket);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you configured the network security group to allow TCP packets on the desired port? I highly suspect the EC2 firewall is throwing away your packets. What is the actual error message? I assume the client sees -> connection time out.

Comment: Check out [these](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#adding-security-group-rule) docs for adding a new rule to the security group if you have not done so already. If the port is added, post the actual socket level error produced by the client, and any error logs from either server or client.